# Lost everything after deleting branch - nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I was cleaning up my branches and merging them. After I am done with the master branch, I tried to checkout otherbranch but it didn't let me do it because there were 2 files that will be overwritten! I used -f to switch branches (I was only expecting to see what changed in that branch). Nothing was in the otherbranch. So I didn't see any danger to delete it. After that, I lost all the other changes in the master branch. Here is what happened! Please let me know how can I revert all changes in the master branch?

```
[kali@core core]$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   blabla.cgi
#   deleted:    blabla2.cgi
#   modified:   blabla3.cgi
#   new file:   blabla4.cgi
#   modified:   blabla5.cgi
#
[kali@core core]$ git merge otherbranch
Already up-to-date.
[kali@core core]$ git merge master
Already up-to-date.
[kali@core core]$ git checkout otherbranch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    blabla3.cgi
    blabla5.cgi
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
[kali@core core]$ git checkout -f otherbranch
Switched to branch 'otherbranch'
[kali@core core]$ git status
# On branch otherbranch
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
[kali@core core]$ git checkout otherbranch
Already on 'otherbranch'
[kali@core core]$ git branch -d otherbranch
error: Cannot delete the branch 'otherbranch' which you are currently on.
[kali@core core]$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
[kali@core core]$ git branch -D otherbranch
Deleted branch otherbranch (was d3c9c6f).
[kali@core core]$ git branch
* master
[kali@core core]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Edit : As Stony suggessted, I run reflog. Here is the output!

```
d302fab HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from otherbranch to master
d3c9c6f HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to otherbranch
d302fab HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from otherbranch to master
d3c9c6f HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from otherbranch to otherbranch
d3c9c6f HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to otherbranch
d302fab HEAD@{5}: pull: Fast-forward
f1569af HEAD@{6}: pull: Fast-forward
d0f72c6 HEAD@{7}: pull: Fast-forward
4c007c4 HEAD@{8}: pull: Fast-forward
d3c9c6f HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from otherbranch to master
d3c9c6f HEAD@{10}: merge master: Fast-forward
506d77d HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from master to otherbranch
d3c9c6f HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from otherbranch to master
506d77d HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from master to otherbranch
d3c9c6f HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from otherbranch to master
506d77d HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving from master to otherbranch
d3c9c6f HEAD@{16}: pull: Fast-forward
72b9fee HEAD@{17}: pull: Fast-forward
2a7f380 HEAD@{18}: pull: Fast-forward
506d77d HEAD@{19}: checkout: moving from otherbranch to master
506d77d HEAD@{20}: checkout: moving from master to otherbranch
506d77d HEAD@{21}: checkout: moving from otherbranch to master
506d77d HEAD@{22}: checkout: moving from master to otherbranch
506d77d HEAD@{23}: commit: (Ticket ####)
0cb7e3a HEAD@{24}: pull: Fast-forward
fef5044 HEAD@{25}: pull: Fast-forward
a92f38f HEAD@{26}: pull: Fast-forward
1715fc0 HEAD@{27}: pull: Fast-forward
8cad089 HEAD@{28}: pull: Fast-forward
ecb5708 HEAD@{29}: pull: Fast-forward
87fd764 HEAD@{30}: commit: (Ticket ###)
745c5ad HEAD@{31}: clone: from git@oldseqcore:/opt/git/seqcore.git/
```

I created couple branches using HEAD@{0}, HEAD@{5}, HEAD@{9} but it didn't help me. I still can't see my old changes both under master or newly created branches.

Comment: The events in your reflog do not match the commands you ran. For example, the reflog should show you checking out `otherbranch`. Did you delete your copy and clone the repository again?

Comment: I changed the names for the sake of example but forgot to do it in the reflog. Now it is updated! Thanks for pointing out @Schwern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear what you mean when you say you lost changes in the master branch. From what you wrote I see two things lost.

1. The uncommitted changes to `blabla*.cgi`.
2. The branch `otherbranch`.

The first one is gone. Uncommitted changes, even if they are staged, cannot be recovered. Sorry. The staging area was overwritten by `git checkout -f`. Git warned you.

```
$ git checkout otherbranch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    blabla3.cgi
    blabla5.cgi
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Git's method of switching branches in a single working copy can be hard to get used to. Lessons to learn from this:

1. Don't use `git checkout -f` ever.
2. Stash your changes before switching branches, `git stash save`.
3. Listen to Git when it doesn't let you do something.

---

`otherbranch` is recoverable.  Git helpfully tells you the ID where it was at.

```
$ git branch -D otherbranch
Deleted branch otherbranch (was d3c9c6f).
```

You can recreate the branch using that ID, `d3c9c6f`.

```
git branch otherbranch d3c9c6f
```

There was no need to use `git branch -D`. You should always use `git branch -d` first. That way you will know that merged branch is actually merged.

---

There is another problem: your reflog does not match the commands you wrote.  Your reflog should show you checking out `otherbranch`, but it doesn't.  This indicates the repository you were doing the checkouts on and the one you did the reflog on are *different repositories*. This might explain why something is missing.

I'm going to guess you deleted your working copy and cloned a fresh repository. If this is the case, you probably had commits in master which were not pushed. They're gone.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern for point out branch name confusion. I changed them before I post it but forgot to do it in reflog. Now it is edited. I choose your answers for the lessons. I am glad that I had a back up now it is mostly recovered.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for changes to `blabla3.cgi` and `blabla5.cgi`, they are gone forever (unless you have backup solutions unrelated to git). They are gone when you did `git checkout -f otherbranch`. What you did afterwards does not matter.

Sadly, `git reflog` can't help you this time because it appears like you never committed them. `git reflog` can help you if you committed something into a branch and then deleted that branch. It can also help you if you committed something and then messed that commit up (e.g. by rebase or --amend)

`git` really means it when it warns you that

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    blabla3.cgi
    blabla5.cgi
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Comment: I actually didn't care about files that will be overwritten when I switched to otherbranch from master. I just don't understand why I lost my changes in the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to work with the reflog.

`git reflog`

Then you can see the reflog. With the id you can restore last changes.

```
22490d2 HEAD@{58}: commit: xxxx
262a092 HEAD@{59}: commit: xx2
0a168bc HEAD@{60}: commit: xx2
```

`git checkout -b my_new_branch HEAD@{60}`

for example. With that you can make a new branch on that point.